# Using standard HTML Elements in KotlinJS safely typed

Tags: javascript, kotlin

I'm trying to dynamically create an image which I will then append to the DOM.

```
import org.w3c.dom.HTMLImageElement

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    // load footer banner image
    val img: HTMLImageElement = HTMLImageElement()
    with (img){
        src = "img/footer.png"
        classList.add("img-responsive")
    }

}
```

However, it doesn't like my constructor `HTMLImageElement()` since `HTMLImageElement` is an interface.

Removing the constructor and Kotlin complains that `img` must be initialised.

What is the correct way to make use of the `HTMLImageElement` in a type-safe way ?

**Update**: I'm now using maven which generates everything as it should.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.blah</groupId>
    <artifactId>blah</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>Blah</name>

    <properties>
        <kotlin.version>1.0.2</kotlin.version>
        <kotlin.html.version>0.5.8</kotlin.html.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>bintray-kotlinx</id>
            <name>bintray</name>
            <url>http://dl.bintray.com/kotlinx/kotlinx</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlinx.html.js</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.html.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

which compiles a `blah.js`, `blah.js.map`, `blah.js.meta`, `kotlin.js`, `kotlinx.html.js`, `kotlinx.html.meta.js`, `kotlinx.html.shared.js`, `kotlinx.html.shared.meta.js` and `stdlib.meta.js`.

In my html file (which is sitting in my root directory) I'm including the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="target/classes/kotlin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="target/classes/kotlinx.html.shared.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="target/classes/blah.js"></script>
```

I've got a `println("hello world")` in my `Main.kt` which executes fine in the browser printing "hello world" in the browswer console.

Now I still want to append that image dynamically using Kotlin ...

The docs say I should be doing `document.create.div("panel")` to create a `div`, but `document.create...` autocompletes to `createAttribute`, `createComment` etc, no `create()` method in sight anywhere. (document is from package 'kotlin.browser').

I'm not exactly sure how to use `kotlinx.html` since what I'm seeing in IntelliJ doesn't match the docs.

How do I append a dynamically created image to an existing div using KotlinJS ?

Comment: Take a look at kotlinx.html

Comment: what jar/maven dependency are you using?

Comment: @pabl0rg: I've added a `pom.xml` now and added it into my post including all the dependencies, repositories, etc.

Comment: @IRus: I take it the docs for kotlinx.html are outdated? Or am I just using it incorrectly ?

Comment: Docs looks up to date. But js and jvm version can be different. For example with `System.out` will not work in kotlinjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just write sample project with **kotlin2js** and **kotlinx.html** [IRus/kotlin-kotlinx.html](https://github.com/IRus/kotlin-kotlinx.html). Looks like current version of **kotlinx.html** (0.5.8) not compatible with Kotlin 1.0.2, but works well with kotlin 1.0.1-2.

Comment: See 0.5.9: it is compatible with 1.0.2

Comment: Error 404, page not found :(